# Zabbix 2.2 SSH/FTP performance monitoring

Tags: ssh, ftp, zabbix

I have a few systems I need to monitor which are out of my control. Ideally I needed a simple ping RTT test to see the status of the link. These systems do not respond to my ping requests so I need to find a workaround. I was thinking I could use SSH or FTP ports (which do respond) to monitor RTT similarly.

I have used this as a part of simple checks but it does not return any response.

```
net.tcp.service.perf[ftp,,21]
```

This is also using Numeric (float) type of information. But it does not return any type of data.

Comment: Item with key "net.tcp.service.perf[]" should either be of type "Zabbix agent", "Zabbix agent (active)" or "Simple check". In the first two cases the item will be processed by the agent, in the third - by the server. Which of these types do you have it set to? Does it become unsupported? If so, what error message do you see? What do you mean by not returning data - does it always return 0 or it is not checked at all?

Comment: As I don't have any access to that system. I can't use the agent, I have used the simple check. It does not say it is not supported. Just does not return any data as a graph of a numeric value. I have however managed to return data (numeric & graphical) on a very similar system.